# Is the meeting in M.42 between Roboute and the Emperor described anywhere?

Tags: warhammer-40k

After his resurrection, Roboute Guilliman has gained an audience with his father, the Emperor of Mankind.

In [the wiki](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Roboute_Guilliman), this is described quite briefly:

> Guilliman was left standing alone before the ornate doorway, dwarfed by its immensity. A single, booming chime rang through the cathedrum processional, and a collective sigh of wonder and fear escaped the pilgrims gathered there as the doorway cracked open. Slowly, silently, the tall doors swung inwards to reveal only darkness and drifting mists beyond.[...] As silently as they had opened, the doors swept closed behind him, and Roboute Guilliman was lost to sight.[...]
>
> Only when the day cycle dawned again with soaring hymns and a swelling glare of lumen-light did the doors finally swing open. Glowing mist spilled from within, silver now like the cold shimmer of moonlight on bones, and from the cold radiance stepped Roboute Guilliman.

Is their meeting described in more details somewhere else?

Comment: Most of the wiki is just copyright violations direct from the books, with occasional pointless additions.

Comment: @OrangeDog this doesn't answer the question. Besides, it is legal to provide a limited quotes from the books

Comment: that's why it's a comment, not an answer. Ten thousand words is also not a "limited quote".

Answer (score 6):

This quote is from chapter 3 "Rise of the Primarch" of the 2010 sourcebook *[The Gathering Storm](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=9781589946989) III: Rise of the Primarch* (WHF04, published by [Fantasy Flight Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Warhammer_Fantasy_Roleplay_publications#2010)).

Your quote appears to be verbatim from the source (p.92).  In fact that ***entire*** section of [Roboute Guilliman's fandom page](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Roboute_Guilliman) seems to be the entire chapter *almost* verbatim.  The differences are what you'd expect from a wiki:

> Hours passed, during which the warriors of the Terran Crusade stood silently to attention before the throne room doors. Awed murmuring amongst the crowds turned to fervent prayer, and more than one petitioner ventured forward to present Captain Sicarius, Grand Master Voldus and their brothers with meagre devotional offerings and words of thanks. Saint Celestine and Inquisitor Greyfax chose this moment to depart, the former to spread her blessings, and the latter to report to her Ordo Hereticus superiors.

has become

> **Solar** hours passed, during which the warriors of the Terran Crusade stood silently to attention before the throne room doors. Awed murmuring amongst the crowds turned to fervent prayer, and more than one petitioner ventured forward to present Captain **Cato** Sicarius, Grand Master **Aldrik** Voldus and their brothers with meagre devotional offerings and words of thanks. **Saint** Celestine and Inquisitor Greyfax chose this moment to depart, the former to spread her blessings, and the latter to report to her Ordo Hereticus superiors **for the first time in many standard centuries**.

with numerous pointless additions.